# Add new button to Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I can add a new link under the dashboard menu in the backend of WP

```
        function new_link_display() {
            echo "Echo html code for the page";
        }

        function new_link_page() {
            if (function_exists('add_submenu_page') )
                add_submenu_page('index.php', __('New Like Label'), __('New Link Label'), 'manage_options', 'new-link-display', 'new_link_display');
        }
        add_action('admin_menu', 'new_link_page');
                }
                add_action('admin_menu', 'new_link_page');
```

How do I add a new button below the Settings button. I don't want it with in the Settings menu but a separate button below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `add_menu_page` instead of `add_submenu_page`

here is your code , that may work.

```
function new_link_display() {
            echo "Echo html code for the page";
}

function new_link_page() {
    if (function_exists('add_submenu_page') )

        add_menu_page( __('New Like Label'), __('New Link Label'), 'manage_options', 'new-link-display', 'new_link_display', $icon_url, $position);
        // $position = If position is not set, menu will at the end automatically.
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'new_link_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'new_link_page');
```

## [Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully read these two pages, first:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Plugin Name
 * Plugin URI: --
 * Description: Plugin INfo
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Plugin Author
 */



$object = new Classname();



add_action('admin_menu',  array($object, 'addMenu'));



class Classname{

    public function addMenu(){
        add_options_page('Main Menu', 'Main Menu', 'manage_options', 'page_name', array($this, 'optionPage'));
    }

    public function optionPage(){
        //code required
    }

}
?>
```